# Root Sage theme styles are not working!

Tags: theme-development, css, localhost

One of the websites that I'm working with has a custom build theme using Sage Roots. It works just fine on the live site and I was trying to setup it up in my localhost to work with it. For some reasons, none of the website styles and working correctly. I checked all the CSS files and made sure all of them are there but still it doesn't work. Is that because I need to install any dependencies for the Sage theme or something else? Any thoughts on this guys?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the URL set correctly to your local URL in Settings > General?

Answer (score 2):

In Sage 9, the asset pipeline comes through Webpack. You'll need to run yarn from the theme root and then start or production build the site with yarn as well.